# Getting my buttons to add text to a list

Tags: button, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm having a problem getting my buttons to actually do something, when one of the buttons on the top left are clicked, I want a text box in the frame below it adding the name of that button to a list but getting really stuck with it, any help would be much appreciated, thank you

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1000x600')

var=tk.StringVar()

Frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
Frame1.configure(background='light blue',height='300',width='500')
Frame1.grid(sticky="nsew",row='0',column='0')

Frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
Frame2.configure(background='grey',height='300',width='500')
Frame2.grid(sticky="nsew",row='0',column='1')

Frame3 = tk.Frame(root)
Frame3.configure(background='grey',height='300',width='500')
Frame3.grid(sticky="nsew",row='1',column='0')

Frame4 = tk.Frame(root)
Frame4.configure(background='light blue',height='300',width='500')
Frame4.grid(sticky="nsew",row='1',column='1')



def PrintOrder():
    LabelOrder = tk.Label(Frame3,text="DONUT ORDER")
    LabelOrder.grid(row='0',column='0')
    return

Button1 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Apple Cinnamon",height='2',width='15',padx=10, pady=5,command=PrintOrder).grid(row='0',column='0')
Button2 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Strawberry",height='2',width='15',padx=10, pady=5,command=PrintOrder).grid(row='0',column='2')
Button3 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Custard",height='2',width='15',padx=10, pady=5,command=PrintOrder).grid(row='0',column='4')
Button4 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Sugar Ring",height='2',width='15',padx=10, pady=5,command=PrintOrder).grid(row='2',column='0')
Button5 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Chocolate Caramel",height='2',width='15',padx=10, pady=5,command=PrintOrder).grid(row='2',column='2')
Button6 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Lemon Circle",height='2',width='15',padx=10, pady=5,command=PrintOrder).grid(row='2',column='4')
Button7 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Blueberry Blaster",height='2',width='15',padx=10, pady=5,command=PrintOrder).grid(row='4',column='0')
Button8 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Strawberry Surprise",height='2',width='15',padx=10, pady=5,command=PrintOrder).grid(row='4',column='2')
Button9 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Simple Sugar",height='2',width='15',padx=10, pady=5,command=PrintOrder).grid(row='4',column='4')

Label1 = tk.Label(Frame2,text="Donut special 6 for the price of 5",height='5',width='30').grid(row='0',column='0')
Button10 = tk.Button(Frame2,text="SPECIAL",padx=5, pady=5,height='5',width='20').grid(row='2',column='0')

Button11 = tk.Button(Frame3,text="ORDER TOTAL",padx=5, pady=5,height='5',width='20').grid(row='2',column='0')


Button12 = tk.Button(Frame4,text="RUNNING TOTAL",padx=5, pady=5,height='5',width='20').grid(row='2',column='0')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you call the `PrintOrder` function, it doesn't necessarily know what button called it.

To fix this, use a `lambda`: [see http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm, "Passing Arguments to Callbacks"]

Also, you'll need variable strings to work with the list.

Above your `PrintOrder` function, write this (move the Label creation outside of the function):

```
LabelContents = tk.StringVar()
LabelOrder = tk.Label(Frame3, textvariable=LabelContents)
LabelOrder.grid(row='0', column='0')
```

then you can update the text in the label.

So change the `PrintOrder` function to

```
def PrintOrder(flavor):
    LabelContents.set(LabelContents.get() + '\n' + flavor)
    return
```

This appends the flavor, with a new line, to the label.

then in the button:

```
 Button(text="lemon", command=lambda: PrintOrder("lemon"))
```

Of course you can modify to fit your program.

For the reasoning behind the lambda, see the link.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That has been a big help, thanks a lot, few more issues but I'll get through them :)